# Unbound local in a function within a function

Tags: python, scope, global, local, python-2.x

I have the following code (written in Python 2.X):

```
def banana(x):
    def apple(stuff):
        x /= 10
        return stuff - x
    return apple(11)
```

When I call `banana`, I get the following error:

```
In [25]: import test

In [26]: test.banana(10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-313a8e4dfaff> in <module>()
----> 1 test.banana(10)

/home/dan/Science/dopa_net/test.py in banana(x)
      3         x /= 10
      4         return stuff - x
----> 5     return apple(11)

/home/dan/Science/dopa_net/test.py in apple(stuff)
      1 def banana(x):
      2     def apple(stuff):
----> 3         x /= 10
      4         return stuff - x
      5     return apple(11)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

It seems to me that `x`, defined in `banana`'s scope, should be available to `apple`, much as a constant defined at the level of a module is available to functions within that module.

I looked around on SO to see what I'd done wrong, and I got the impression that I should have declared `x` as a `global` within `apple`.  This, however, failed for me as well:

```
In [27]: reload(test)
Out[27]: <module 'test' from 'test.py'>

In [28]: test.banana(10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-313a8e4dfaff> in <module>()
----> 1 test.banana(10)

/home/dan/Science/dopa_net/test.py in banana(x)
      4         x /= 10
      5         return stuff - x
----> 6     return apple(11)

/home/dan/Science/dopa_net/test.py in apple(stuff)
      2     def apple(stuff):
      3         global x
----> 4         x /= 10
      5         return stuff - x
      6     return apple(11)

NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Variables in the closure count as non-local; try `nonlocal x`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe forgot to mention i'm on python 2.X.

Comment: Ah, then you can't access it unless you do e.g. `def apple(stuff, x=x):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Global" means global to the module.  Your `x` is not global; it is local to `banana`, but not to `apple`.

In Python 3, you can use `nonlocal x` to make `x` assignable inside `apple`.  In Python 2 there is no way to assign to `x` from inside `apple`.  You must use a workaround such as making `x` a mutable object and mutating it (instead of assigning to it) in `apple`.

Comment: Or add `x=x` to the definition of `apple`.

Comment: OK, so, with python 2, i can *use* x inside apple; i just can't *assign* to it.  that works for me.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That will let you assign to something called `x`, but your assignments won't affect the `x` in the enclosing function.

Comment: @BrenBarn that's true, it depends what the actual aim is